# Zeppelin spark RDD commands fail yet work in spark-shell

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-cassandra-connector, apache-zeppelin

I have setup a standalone single node "cluster" running the following:

- Cassandra 2.2.2
- Spark 1.5.1
- List item
- Compiled fat jar for Spark-Cassandra-Connector 1.5.0-M2
- Compiled Zeppelin 0.6 snapshot 
  compiled with:
  mvn -Pspark-1.5 -Dspark.version=1.5.1 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -Phadoop-2.4 -DskipTests clean package

I can work perfectly fine with spark shell retrieving data from cassandra

I have altered the Zeppelin-env.sh as follow:

```
export MASTER=spark://localhost:7077
export SPARK_HOME=/root/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/
export ZEPPELIN_PORT=8880
export ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.jars=/opt/sparkconnector/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.5.0-M2-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspark.cassandra.connection.host=localhost"
export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR="/root/gowalla-spark-demo/notebooks/zeppelin"
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--jars /opt/sparkconnector/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.5.0-M2-SNAPSHOT.jar --deploy-mode cluster"
export ZEPPELIN_INTP_JAVA_OPTS=$ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS
```

I then start adding paragraphs to a notebook and import the following first:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

Not sure if all of these are necessary. This paragraph runs fine.

Then I do the following:

```
val checkins = sc.cassandraTable("lbsn", "checkins")
```

This runs fine and returns:

```
checkins: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow] = CassandraTableScanRDD[0] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15
```

Then the next paragraph - the follow 2 statements are run -the first succeeds and the second fails:

```
checkins.count
checkins.first
```

Result:

```
res13: Long = 138449
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not find creator property with name 'id' (in class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope)
at [Source: {"id":"4","name":"first"}; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:843)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:533)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:220)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:143)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:409)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:358)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:265)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:245)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:143)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:439)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3558)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2578)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.fromJson(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$34.apply(RDD.scala:1582)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$34.apply(RDD.scala:1582)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.<init>(RDD.scala:1582)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.<init>(CassandraRDD.scala:15)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.<init>(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.copy(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:92)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.copy(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.limit(CassandraRDD.scala:103)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.take(CassandraRDD.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1312)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1311)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:59)
at $iwC.<init>(<console>:61)
at <init>(<console>:63)
at .<init>(<console>:67)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:655)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:620)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:613)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:276)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:170)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:118)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why does the call to first fail. Calls such as sc.fromTextFile also fail.

the following also works:

```
checkins.where("year = 2010 and month=2 and day>12 and day<15").count()
```

but this does not:

```
checkins.where("year = 2010 and month=2 and day>12 and day<15").first()
```

Please assist as this is driving me insane. Especially since the spark shell works but this does not or at least seems partially broken.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not find creator property with name 'id' (in class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope)
at [Source: {"id":"4","name":"first"}; line: 1, column: 1]`

This exception occurs when there're two or more version of jackson libraries in the classpath.

Make sure your Spark Interpreter process has only a single version of jackson library in the classpath.

Comment: Here is an example of this problem occurring when including aws-java-sdk.  Solution in this case would be similar.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511804/zeppelin-spark-reading-parquet-from-s3-throws-nosuchmethoderror-com-fasterxm/45842852#45842852