# Zeppelin + Spark: Reading Parquet from S3 throws NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Using Zeppelin 0.7.2 binaries from the main download, and Spark 2.1.0 w/ Hadoop 2.6, the following paragraph:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet(DATA_URL).filter(FILTER_STRING).na.fill("")
```

Produces the following:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer$.handledType()Ljava/lang/Class;
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.NumberDeserializers$.<init>(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala:49)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.NumberDeserializers$.<clinit>(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.ScalaNumberDeserializersModule$class.$init$(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala:61)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:20)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:37)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<clinit>(DefaultScalaModule.scala)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.parallelize(SparkContext.scala:715)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.mergeSchemasInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:594)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.inferSchema(ParquetFileFormat.scala:235)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:184)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:184)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:183)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:387)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:441)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:425)
  ... 47 elided
```

This error does not happen in the normal spark-shell, only in Zeppelin.  I have attempted the following fixes, which do nothing:

- Download jackson 2.6.2 jars to the zeppelin lib folder and restart
- Add jackson 2.9 dependencies from the maven repositories to the interpreter settings
- Deleting the jackson jars from the zeppelin lib folder

Googling is turning up no similar situations.  Please don't hesitate to ask for more information, or make suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I added `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk` and `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws` as dependencies for the Spark interpreter.  These dependencies bring in their own versions of `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:*` and conflict with Spark's.

You also must exclude `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:*` from other dependencies, this is an example `${ZEPPELIN_HOME}/conf/interpreter.json` Spark interpreter depenency section:

`"dependencies": [
        {
          "groupArtifactVersion": "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4",
          "local": false,
          "exclusions": ["com.fasterxml.jackson.core:*"]
        },
        {
          "groupArtifactVersion": "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1",
          "local": false,
          "exclusions": ["com.fasterxml.jackson.core:*"]
        }
      ]`

Comment: Removing org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.0 from Zeppelin artifacts/dependencies worked for me as well.

Comment: Thanks mate, that fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to include it right in the notebook cell:

```
%dep
z.load("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.2")
```

Comment: z.load should be the same functionally as the second option already tried above: Add jackson 2.9 dependencies from the maven repositories to the interpreter settings.